# Daily reward on iOS game

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a game, and I wanted to implement a daily reward system; in order to give some coins every day.
The system would be similar to a lot of known games like `Angry Birds Friends` or `Shadowgun: Deadzone`. Each day, the first time that I open the app it gives me 5 coins. Then the next day gives me more than 5 coins, and so on till the last day that gives me an item.

The thing is that I don't know where and how to start. Is there any library available to do this or a simple way to implement it? I never developed with dates (using `NSDate` for example) that's why I don't know what to do. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to implement this server side, unless you really just don't care about people gaming it.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I don't understand you.

Comment: He's saying they might have ways to mess with the client. For example, adjusting system time, uninstalling and reinstalling the app, using the app across devices, etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need to implement a server. All you need to do is find a website you trust that displays the date.  Every time the app loads you can make a call to that website and parse to find the date.  You then save this date in `NSUserDefaults` and compare it each time the app opens

EDIT

You will need to find a webpage that displays the current time (search google to find one) then with your code you will need to parse through that page to get the string that contains the date.  Inside of your appDelegate you will want to do something along the lines of this once you get the string

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: myDateAsAStringValue];
```

at this point you will want to save it into NSUserDefaults so

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefault] setObject:myDate forKey:@"lastDatePlayed"];
```

you should also add some logic to compare it to the last date... but that shouldnt be too hard to figure out

Comment: Really? Can you give me more details?

Comment: With this solution every time the website changes its web page structure the application will stop to work (it won't find the correct time)

Comment: this is true, but it also prevents you from having to set up your own server.

Comment: -1 poor solution by relying in one website to do that, unless he has the control which would mean... he has a server

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want to pay for server.. there are many ways of doing things and sometimes they involve tradeoffs.  I said **trusted** up at the top.  Obviously _you_ wouldnt do it that way but if he doesn't want to make a server this is a viable solution.  Take a look at this http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi

Answer (score 3):

You would need to implement this on a server and compare with the last time the user played the game.  If you use the device's date, `NSDate *date = [NSDate date];` the user can simply change the date on his/her device and make it look to your game as if it was a new day.

Comment: You are right, it would be like cheating. So I need to implement a server first? Hum, this looks pretty hard...

Comment: @Vergmort: It needs to be one on which you can do APNS too, unfortunately, so it needs socket support.

Comment: Excelent, I will talk it with other devs right now. Lots of thanks for the answers.

Comment: I can recommend using  [http://www.Parse.com] for easy, free, server/cloud integration.

Comment: @GabCas Is easy to implement on iOS developing?

Answer (score 2):

I do that (not for games but for regular apps, which regarding that there is no difference)

I do that on the server side, pretty much I have a web server which communicates with the app through http (sending and receiving data in json format), I have json parsers in both sides.

in the server side, I have a running  Service which every beginning of the day (compares hour!)  runs my code to update points to my server database

the exposed web-service to my app of course is retrieving that calculated data in the database
and making it available in json

it works the same